# Fetch Gmail Inbox with attachments

Tags: c#, email, smtp, pop3

I have tried the code available over here: [Fetch Gmail Inbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET) which works fine but I also want attachments to be downloaded on the local disk.

Is there any possible solution...?

**EDIT**

Yes..I have done it with the help of `Openpop.dll` from here [Accessing mail with Pop - Using C# and OpenPop](http://www.floresense.com/resc_center/?art=1407) But I want to fetch only Unread Emails from Inbox...Is it Possible..?

Comment: Hint: POP3 *always* fetches the whole message - including the attachments. How have you tried to parse the attachments out of the message?

Comment: Yes..I have done it with the help of `Openpop.dll` from here(http://www.floresense.com/resc_center/?art=1407) But I want to fetch only Unread Emails from Inbox...Is it Possible..?

Comment: POP3 doesn't have a concept of "unread e-mails"; that's completely up to your code to implement. All POP3 does is say "Here's a list of binary blobs contained in your inbox" and "sending blob number x". Anything beyond that needs to be done client-side (by your code, that is).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been using [the MailBee component by Afterlogic](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components) in some of my work projects. It can handle pretty much anything e-mail related the internet could throw at you.

It's a paying product, though, and only useable for 30 days for free, so unfortunately not really an option if you're just coding for yourself.

Comment: MailBee FTW, it really does everything.